# sniffing POST method is this code secure?

Tags: php, security, packet-sniffers, sniffing

Hello every one I've just wrote an php code for my site as gateway 
I  want to know if an hacker sniff the web page and find my MerchantId or no ?

```
 <?php

$MerchantID = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'; //Required
$Amount = 1000; //Amount will be based on Toman - Required
$Description = 'some describtion'; // Required
$Email = 'UserEmail@Mail.Com'; // Optional
$Mobile = '09123456789'; // Optional
$CallbackURL = 'http://www.yoursoteaddress.ir/verify.php'; // Required


$client = new SoapClient('https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/services/WebGate/wsdl', ['encoding' => 'UTF-8']);

$result = $client->PaymentRequest(
[
'MerchantID' => $MerchantID,
'Amount' => $Amount,
'Description' => $Description,
'Email' => $Email,
'Mobile' => $Mobile,
'CallbackURL' => $CallbackURL,
]
);
?>
```

Comment: Your page needs to be using https and you need to save the certificate from https://www.zarinpal.com on the server and force SoapClient to use it otherwise soapclient will not encrypt the data.

Comment: so without https is not secure ,yes?

Comment: indeed you need to use https otherwise the attacker should still sniff the http traffic assuming the attacker is on the same network